# How to float a Div outside an iframe?

Tags: iframe

How do I show a floater, that is within an iframe on my site, but the floater appears on any website and not only within the iframe?

I am sending a sample in fiddle floater (code).

Remember that this code will stay within a iframe within my site. When the person clicks on the link, the floater appears throughout the site and not only within the iframe. Is it possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible as a div cannot be displayed outside of the constraints of the iframe's viewport.  Otherwise, the web would be ripe with all kinds of crazy tricks.

Answer (score 1):

It may be possible by having Javascript outside of the iframe, that can communicate with content within the iframe. Basically, have the Javascript copy the div from the iframe and write it external of the iframe.